# Selectize.js не выводит результаты на русском языке

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-select

Есть **<select>** поле, используемое с плагином [selectize.js](https://selectize.dev/). Данные для выбора загружаются по ajax запросу. **Проблема:** данные на английском языке автоматически выводятся при вводе запроса, данные на русском языке появляются только если снять фокус с **<select>** поля и снова кликнуть на него. **Вопрос:** как сделать чтобы русский работал как английский?

Я пытался использовать JSON.parse после ajax'a, не помогло, а может неправильно использовал.

Скриншот с английским (результаты появляются сразу во время ввода):
[image]

Скриншот с русским (ничего не появляется, хотя в отладке видно, что результаты ajax запроса уже пришли):
[image]

После расфокуса и фокуса:
[image]

html:

```html
<div>
    <label for="su">Source:</label>
    <select id="su"></select>
</div>
```

js:

```js
$('#su').selectize({
    maxItems: 1,
    valueField: "id",
    labelField: "title",
    searchField: ["title"],
    create: false,

    load: (query, callback) => {
        if(!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/search-sources-select/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'query': query},
            success: (res) => callback(res.data),
            error: () => callback(),
        });
    },

    render: {
        option: (item, escape) => {
            return '<p>' + item.title + '</p>'
        }
    }
});
```

django view:

```py
def search_sources_select(request):
    query = request.GET.get("query", "[{]}(2")
    data = Source.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
    data = [
        {
            "id": source.pk,
            "title": source.title,
            "type": source.get_readable_type(),
        }
        for source in data
    ]
    return JsonResponse({"data": data}, status=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Передавайте в опциях `respect_word_boundaries: false`:

```
$('#su').selectize({
    maxItems: 1,
    valueField: "id",
    labelField: "title",
    searchField: ["title"],
    create: false,
    respect_word_boundaries: false,

    load: (query, callback) => {
        if(!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/search-sources-select/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'query': query},
            success: (res) => callback(res.data),
            error: () => callback(),
        });
    },

    render: {
        option: (item, escape) => {
            return '<p>' + item.title + '</p>'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Постарайтесь в будущем оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Было бы неплохо, если бы вы поправили и этот ответ через ссылку [edit], которая находится под сообщением.

Comment: @Глеб вы всегда можете оставить свой развернутый ответ, если вас не устраивает чужой.

Comment: Я оставил коммент из очереди проверок "сообщения низкого качества". Это стандартная фраза для слишком кратких ответов. В хаваскрипте я вообще не смыслю) Теперь ответ нормальный.